# Trying to create a webpage that has different text depending on what is select from a menu

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to set up a webpage that has different menu selections and when a menu item is selected text is displayed in a separate section (depending on what text has been selected).

Here is a link to a webpage that illustrates what i am trying to achieve.

https://www.facebook.com/nrmainsurance/app_282857945119270

This is the code I have come up with as a attempt, I am open to easier ways.  I have also looked at jquery, ajax, if else codes, onlick event listeners (but not fully grasping them).

I am open to suggestions.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table width="80%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
   <tr>
       <td>
           <div align="center">
              <a href="#Step1" class="menuNav">
                  <strong>Step 1</strong>
              </a>
           </div>
        </td>
        <td>
           <div align="center">
              <a href="#Step2" class="menuNav">
                  <strong>Step 2</strong>
              </a>
           </div>
         </td>
         <td>
           <div align="center">
              <a href="#Step3" class="menuNav">
                  <strong>Step 3</strong>
              </a>
           </div>
         </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
<object type="text/html" width="80" height="150" border="thin">
       <?php
         if( onClick "#Step1" ) {
            echo (i hope this work ) ?>
        <?php

         } else { }
       ?>
    </object> 
</object> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to create tabs menu. You can use jQuery Ui tabs for this purpose. Here is a basic demo http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ . If you want to do a little bit of styling then see this link http://keith-wood.name/uiTabs.html

Comment: aww you beat me by 4 seconds. Haha +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery to achieve this effect. It's really easy too! 
I think this is what you're looking for.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

PHP don't have "onclick" function. it's on javascript.

You can find working script at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/tabcontent.htm just change the styling of the css to get the desired design.